# How Do I Generate Dynamic Contols Based On Selected Months From Ajaxtoolkit:Calendarextender?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my `.aspx` page, Value appears in text box based on selected month from `ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender`.

I have to generate dynamic labels and textboxes based on selected month's days.

I will generate dynamic controls based on selected month.

but how can I fire event/function in `aspx.cs` file just after select the month from `ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender`.

I have to tried to find the solution in google from last 2 day but without any success.

In aspx page

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtHoliDate" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtHoliDate_TextChanged" />
<asp:ImageButton runat="Server" ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Admin/Images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png" AlternateText="Click to show calendar" Height="15px" CausesValidation="False"  /><br />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtHoliDate"                                        PopupButtonID="Image1" TodaysDateFormat="d MMMM, yyyy" Format="dd-MM-yyyy" CssClass="clsCalendar" />
```

in aspx.cs file

```
protected void txtHoliDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
// Some code here...
    }
```

Comment: Some code that you have tried please?

Comment: consider using a function that triggers when the value in your textbox is updated. If you need help coding it, post your own current code, so people can fill in the gaps.

Comment: I want to call text change event in aspx.cs file after change the value in ajax calendar control.